# Laravel seeding my tables(many to many relation) fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am building an authentication system in Laravel where a user can have different roles. I have three tables. `users`, `roles`, `role_user` and

```
users
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| username       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| name           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| surname        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| email          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| role_id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| password       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| remember_token | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+

roles
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| role  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

role_user
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| role_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to seed my tables:

```
class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        Schema::table('roles')->delete();
        Role::create(array(
            'role'     => 'Superadmin'
        ));
        Role::create(array(
            'role'     => 'Admin'
        ));
        Role::create(array(
            'role'     => 'User'
        ));

        Schema::table('users')->delete();
        User::create(array(
            'name'     => 'John',
            'surname'     => 'Svensson',
            'username' => 'John_superadmin',
            'email'    => 'john.svensson@gmail.com',
            'role_id'   => 1,
            'password' => Hash::make('1234'),
        ));
        User::create(array(
            'name'     => 'Carl',
            'surname'     => 'Svensson',
            'username' => 'Calle S',
            'email'    => 'carl.svensson@gmail.com',
            'role_id'   => 2,
            'password' => Hash::make('1111'),
        ));
    }

}
```

To my question: How do i seed the role_user table? Do i need a model for that? With user and role table i have the model User and Role.

```
class Role extends Eloquent{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
    }
}
```

The fail i get when i try seed is:

```
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::table() must be an instance of Closure, none given
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues with your code. First of all your error is because of this:

```
Schema::table('roles')->delete();
```

`Schema` class is only used for the schema builder, which is already done at this point. You don't need to use the `Schema` class here. Instead use the `DB` class.

```
DB::table('roles')->delete();
```

The next problem, no where in your code are you actually assigning roles. The `role_id` in your user table is pointless, since you are supposed to be assigning roles using a pivot table.

`role_id` in your users table in a one-to-many relationship, not many-to-many, like the pivot table.

In order to assign John the role of Superadmin:

```
// Create the role
$superadmin = Role::create(array(
    'role'     => 'Superadmin'
));


// Create the user
$user = User::create(array(
    'name'     => 'John',
    'surname'     => 'Svensson',
    'username' => 'John_superadmin',
    'email'    => 'john.svensson@gmail.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('1234'),
));

// Assign roles using one of several methods:

// Syncing
$user->roles()->sync([$superadmin->id]);

// or attaching
$user->roles()->attach($superadmin->id);

// or save
$user->roles()->save($superadmin);
```

Comment: You are right. Since its just i pivot table i guess i dont need a model for that? And i guess i should only specify the belongsToMany relation in the User model.

Comment: You don't need a model for a pivot table. If you want users to have more than one role, stick with the pivot table and get rid of the `role_id` on the user table.

Comment: "role_id in your users table in a one-to-many relationship, not one-to-many, like the pivot table" Did you mean many-to-many ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct `Schema::table` to `DB::table`, like already suggested.

However the easiest and most performant way to seed pivot table is something like this:

```
$users = User::listst('id');

$roles = Role::lists('id');

$usersRoles = [
   // assign roles to users however you like - manually
];

// or maybe in a foreach look

// then run single insert
DB::table('role_user')->insert($usresRoles);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the error message. `Schema::table()` expects something like this:

```
Schema::table('table_name', function($table)
{
    // actions inside of the closure function
});
```

Whereas you have:

```
Schema::table('roles')->delete();
```

What you're looking for is the `DB::table('roles')->delete()` or `DB::table('roles')->truncate()` function:

```
// performs a delete, safe for use with foreign keys
// you can use truncate where you don't have to worry about foreign keys
DB::table('roles')->delete();
```

More information can be [found in the docs section regarding record deletion](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#deletes).

Comment: This is incorrect. `delete()` truncates the table values, which is what the OP wants. `drop()` and `dropIfExists()` deletes the actual table all together. There won't be a `roles` table anymore after that command. And `delete()` is apart of the `DB` class anyways, not `Schema` (see my answer).

Comment: Fair point, I was assuming he was trying to delete the table for whatever reason. Will update.